# Как подключить конструктор в SQLite Ionic?

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, npm, ionic

Есть файл app.module.ts . В нем я прописал команду

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

Далее идет команда на конструктор:

```
constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) { }

...

this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {


    db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));


  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Как результат, Lint подчеркивает и говорит мне, что не удается найти имя "constructor"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, где его нужно прописать, это имя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где у вам написан код `constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) { }`?

Comment: app.module.ts . Коллеги говорят, что конструктор должен быть объявлен в Классе. в каком же и где он

Comment: Коллеги правду говорят. Вам нужно создать класс и в нем объявлять конструктор.

Comment: Дефолтного класса нет? где же его смотреть, чтобы не создавать

Comment: Я даже не знаю, как ответить. Это надо знать структуру вашего проекта, что в нем есть.